# Flutter TextField gets empty when first typed Space

Tags: flutter

I'm using TextField with some initial value. But when I want to add more text like append after that initial value, but always first time I type "space" the TextField gets emptied. Why is this so?

Another annoying thing is why first time tap to TextField the cursor always get to the left not after initial value?

```
var textEditingController = TextEditingController();
textEditingController.text = 'some_initial_values';

TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(

  ),
  controller: textEditingController,      
)
```

**Edit:**
I get the initial values from StreamBuilder via ListView.Builder not a static text.

Comment: can you leave out decoration

Answer (score 0):

looking at the source code of `TextField`, might best answer this question.

```
if (widget.decoration != null) {
      child = AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: Listenable.merge(<Listenable>[ focusNode, controller ]),
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
          return InputDecorator(
            decoration: _getEffectiveDecoration(),
            baseStyle: widget.style,
            textAlign: widget.textAlign,
            isFocused: focusNode.hasFocus,
            isEmpty: controller.value.text.isEmpty,
            child: child,
          );
        },
        child: child,
      );
    }
```

The `InputDecorator` class has a `textAlign` and a `isEmpty` property that I thinks causing the behaviour you are referring to. Leaving out decoration: The default behaviour is the one you desire.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';


void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var textEditingController = TextEditingController();
    textEditingController.text = 'some_initial_values';

    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Transition Animation Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: TextField(
            controller: textEditingController,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I still experiencing this behavior. I also remove the decoration as you said. The only thing I notice now is that my TextField showing some initial values from StreamBuilder via ListView.Builder. If I use static initial value all ok.